# How to use native node modules in sveltekit?

Tags: typescript, vite, svelte, sveltekit

I want to use a native node module ([@zk-email/zk-regex-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zk-email/zk-regex-compiler)) in svelte (I'm using sveltekit and vite), the native module has been built using neon rust (https://neon-bindings.com/) which I presume is the same build as node-pre-gyp. I tried import in normally

```js
import compiler from "@zk-email/zk-regex-compiler"
```

It is giving me the following error.

> [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/routes/+page.svelte: failed to import "/node_modules/@zk-email/zk-regex-compiler/index.node"
>
> |- Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. You may need to install appropriate plugins to handle the .node file format, or if it's an asset, add "**/*.node" to `assetsInclude` in your configuration.

Here's is my vite.config.js

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});
```

I have tried https://github.com/vite-plugin/vite-plugin-native with the following vite.config.js

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import native from 'vite-plugin-native';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit(), native({ target: 'esm' })],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});
```

But I receive the following error with it

> Cannot find module '../dist-native/index.node'
> Require stack:
>
> - /Users/paradox/Desktop/projects/zkemail/zk-regex-ui/native:../dist-native/index.node

Comment: You'll need to pre-process the Node module (assuming CommonJS module) so it is transformed to native ESM.  By name, maybe vite-plugin-commonjs is what you need.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might want to specify if the problem is limited to `npm run build` (or `dev` is affected too) and if you're using `@sveltejs/adapter-node`. I'd also try to configure the vite-plugin-native with an absolute `outDir` to see if the `.node` file is there.